# Computer-aided musicology

Tags: theory

I have been trying to explore music theory concepts programmatically, namely through [music21](http://mit.edu/music21/) software, but I've run into a lot of trouble. Are there any other frameworks for this?

Comment: Here again, it would help if the people voting to close state their arguments. Sometimes a bad or subjective question can be rephrased by the original poster in a useful way.

Comment: If making it work properly in an IDE is the issue, you should try PyDev for Eclipse, or PyScripter for an easier setup that's not Eclipse.  I've found the easiest PyDev in Eclipse environment is Aptana Studio, which is a tailored Eclipse that easily loads PyDev as a module.  Perhaps this is because Aptana is also responsible for PyDev.

Comment: The problem here is the lack of definition of "trouble".

Comment: I agree, this question is extremely unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "explore music theory concepts programmatically?" Are you trying to learn music theory? Write scripts to automatically generate parts of songs for analysis?

Answer (score 4):

I was not aware of music21, but it looks interesting.  Another, somewhat older, Java-based framework is [Rubato](http://www.rubato.org/).  I am using it in my thesis research, but I do not know how much it is currently being maintained.

Comment: what is your thesis about?

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of another Python-based system called Sebastian https://github.com/jtauber/sebastian but it's at a very early stage. I'd be interested to know what you felt want lacking in music21 in case Sebastian could (eventually) meet your needs better.

Comment: The main thing that was lacking is a could not make it work properly in any IDE (netBeans and Eclipse)